# zxing how to decode from a file?

Tags: android, decoding, zxing

I am developing an application based on the zxing library and I would like the user to be able to decode a photo that is stored on the sd card.

I have found an example under the androidTest example but when I tried to use it I found that in class BenchmarkThread in line 96 eclipse complained that HybridBinarizer is not known.

what I have to import in order to make it work?

also is there any other example I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HybridBinarizer is in the project's core/ module. That code also needs to be present and available to your build to work. The provided Ant script, naturally, does this for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help I guess that I have to run ant and include the jar in the class-path instead of importing the source files.